# Link selector using find for chaining divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am trying to change input selection to link selection which will be hiding and showing div layers. It looks like my selector is not working correctly since when I select something nothing is happening. Any help how I can resolve this situation are welcome. Here is my code

**HTML:**

```
<li><a class="btn-default" id="Section1" name="options-doc">link 1</a></li>  
<li><a class="btn-default" id="Section2" name="options-doc">link 2</a></li>  


<div class="types" data-period='Section1'></div>
<div class="types" data-period='Section2'></div>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {              
      $(".btn-default").click(function(){
      var test = $(this).find("a[name$='options-doc']").id();
        $(".types").hide();
        $(".types[data-period='" + test + "']").show();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.id()` is not a method in `jQuery`(or javascript for that matter).

Also, in this case, do not use `find()` as `this` is the clicked anchor itself

Try using [**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
var test = $(this).attr('id');
```